# How to link a domain ontology with WordNet synsets?

Tags: ontology, wordnet, protege

I have created a domain ontology for emotions. My task is to detect emotions conveyed in comments, posted on some forum. I want to populate each class of emotion (e.g., Joy) with its synonyms (e.g., Happy, Glad, etc.) using WordNet synsets, but I don't know how. I tried using IRI to create individuals but no luck so far. I'm using Protege 4.3.

Previously, a plugin called WordNetTab was available, but it is no longer supported (http://protege.cim3.net/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?WordNetTab).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no plugins that work with Protégé version 4.3 or greater. (I looked at the [WordNet Princeton Related Projects](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/related-projects/) page, Ontoling was a plugin someone created but it works with Protégé 3.2 only). You may have to resort to

1) Rolling back to a much older version of Protégé .

2) Using a Java (Or your preferred programming language)  api for wordnet (like JAWS) along with a Java (again preference) based ontology framework (like OWL API or Apache Jena) to create these links. 

3) Write a Protégé plugin for WordNet yourself!

Comment: Yes, you are right; I know about OntoLing. I'm working on Java and know a little about Jena API but don't know how to carry out what you've mentioned. Can you please elaborate?I'll look into JAWS. Thanks.

Comment: Sure I can give you a brief overview of how to use Jena. Basically you want to use its Ontology api to load your ontology file so that you can use other api calls against it. So what you'd do is set up JAWS, get the data for the individuals you want to make and then use Jena to put them into the ontology.